# Updating span with jQuery, fetching it with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jQuery-script that updates a span when the user clicks on different buttons. It updates and displays as desired. 
But I want to fetch this "variable" with PHP and input it into a file.
When the document loads the value of the span is 0, and gets higher as the user click specific buttons. When I write the value of the span to my text file it is always 0. Help?

jQuery:

```
$(".button").click(function()
{   
    $(this).addClass("button-clicked");

    $(this).siblings(".button").addClass("disabled");

    $(this).siblings(".rett").addClass("rett-ved-feil");

    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).siblings(".button").unbind("click");

    if($(this).hasClass("rett"))
    {
        rettVar++;

        $("#antall-rett").html(rettVar);
        $("#score").html(rettVar);

        $(this).addClass("button-clicked-riktig");
    }

});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument; 
        $doc->loadHTMLFile('index.php'); 
        $node = $doc->getElementById('score'); 

        $score = $node->nodeValue;

        $fil = fopen("score.txt","a");

        $loglinje =  $_POST["navn"] . ": " . $score;

        fwrite ($fil, $loglinje . "\n");
        fclose($fil);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<title>Huskampanje Quiz</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mediaqueries.css">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">   

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/scrollToggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<section class="section" id="intro">

    <div class="content">

        <h1>Huskampanje quiz<br /><span class="handsome">Ta quizen her</span></h1>

    </div>

    <a href="#brannskader-section"><img src="img/pil.png" id="pil" /></a>

</section>
```

```
<section class="section" id="håndverker-section">

    <div class="content">

        <p>

            Når det gis et prisoverslag på en håndverkertejeneste kan endelig pris maks overstige..

        </p>

        <span class="button">5%</span>
        <span class="button">10%</span>
        <span class="button rett">15%</span>
        <span class="button">20%</span>

        <span class="steps">4/10</span>

    </div>

</section>
```

```
<section class="section" id="naturskade-section">

    <div class="content">

        <p>

            Ved påsketider har snøen ligget en stund på hyttetak, og oppnår høyere egenvekt enn når den er fersk. Om vi har et 
            hyttetak på 100 kvadratmeter og snødybden er 1 meter vil vekten av snøen være omlag..

        </p>

        <span class="button rett">30 tonn</span>
        <span class="button">10 tonn</span>
        <span class="button">5 tonn</span>
        <span class="button">20 tonn</span>

        <span class="steps">10/10</span>

    </div>

</section>
```

```
<ul id="sticky">

    <li id="header-sticky">Antall rett</li>

    <li id="antall-rett">0</li>

</ul>
```

```
<section id="resultat">

    <div class="content" id="resultat-content">

        <div class="score">

            <span id="score">0</span>

            <form action="index.php" method="post">

                <input type="text" name="navn">
                <input type="submit" name="submit">

            </form>
            <?php



    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument; 
        $doc->loadHTMLFile('index.php'); 
        $node = $doc->getElementById('score'); 

        $score = $node->nodeValue;

        $fil = fopen("score.txt","a");

        $loglinje =  $_POST["navn"] . ": " . $score;

        fwrite ($fil, $loglinje . "\n");
        fclose($fil);
    }

?>
        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're fetching the data from the PHP which you would typically do with AJAX.

Comment: My span has an id of "score". I'm trying to get the html of the span with $score = $node->nodeValue; But I'm not sure if that's the way to do it.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your full HTML code.

Comment: OMG, yes, that is how stupid I am. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Fenistil There's no need to be condescending like that. Everyone has got to start somewhere. Wouldn't it be better if you can offer something concrete and constructive?

Comment: @MortenHauge You will have to make an AJAX call: JS is a client-side language while PHP is server-side. Do you have the intention to store the value? You might want to rely on a DB for that case.

Comment: @Terry I'm sorry for being condescending, I hope my answer will be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they told you, Javascript is client side while PHP is server side.

This means that what in client side happends, stays there and server doesn't care at all. If you want to update your file with the value, you got two ways to do it.

1.AJAX, send the value async to a php file and write the value desired into your file/database...

2.Make a form and retrieve the data and save it where you want. For this, make hidden inputs for example that will increment with every click.

Edit: for number 2, if you have multiple pages, you can have an input hidden with name, for example: "right_answers"

```
<form>
    ...
    <!-- first page -->
    <input type="hidden" name="right_answers" value="0">
    ...
</form>
```

Then in the next page, at the start, check if the answer is correct:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['question'] == "answer") {
        $goodAnswer = $_POST['right_answers']+1;
    }
    else {
        $goodAnswer = $_POST['right_answer'];
    }
?>
<form>
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="right_answers" value="<?php echo $goodAnswers; ?>">
    ...
</form>
```

This way you will always know the correct answers the user made. It's just an idea, sure there are better ways.

Comment: Option #2 sounds good. This is a quiz, and I increase and show how many right answers the user has as they go along. At the end I want them to submit their name and also store their score in the text file. How would I make "hidden inputs" with the spans I use as buttons? Can I do this with only PHP, or would I still have to use AJAX?

Comment: if you are doing multiple php pages instead of using AJAX, you can have a hidden input with name, for example, "right_answers", at the start of the page check if the answer is good and increment the value and set it. You can do this for every page. I'll update my answer in while

Comment: Hmm.. All the questions are in one html/php document. Can I do like a little php-snippet for every button (span) that is the right answer on every question that increases an integer, and then store that variable together with the users name when they submit at form at the end of the quiz? Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: if it's on the same page, you can make jQuery tricks to display the questions, that when you click on one answer, you can update an input hidden in case the clicked answer is the correct, hide the question and show the next one, and at the end you can submit the whole form for having all the information

Comment: The quiz is all layed out and works fine. My problem is how to store the JS variable with the amount of right answers to the file. I just need to fetch that variable at the end when the user submits the form with their name.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129915/get-inner-html-with-php Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP script (file) will run on your server. The user, who has opened your webpage somewhere in the world, can't and never should see or alter your server-side files, like your PHPs. Every user who opens your webpage sees the same PHP, so if 5 users are browsing your page, they are all see the content that index.php has generated for them. The output of your PHP file (a HTML code) will be in their browsers (in the users computer's memory), and you can modify it with jQuery. It will always remain in the memory of the users' computer. So if you want to save something a user typed, you have to send it back to your server and here a PHP can catch it and save it for you. But it's not a good idea to save it to a file, since if 5 users sending back data, you should save 5 separate files for them (and you have to identify all users). But the basics are here:

You have to make a PHP file that can catch your input, save it as ajax.php:

```
<?php
    $fil = fopen("score.txt","a");
    $loglinje =  "score:".$score;
    fwrite ($fil, $loglinje . "\n");
    fclose($fil);
?>
```

Then you have to send the data back to the server, so your jQuery code should something like that:

```
<script>
$(".button").click(function()
{   
    $(this).addClass("button-clicked");

    $(this).siblings(".button").addClass("disabled");

    $(this).siblings(".rett").addClass("rett-ved-feil");

    $(this).unbind("click");
    $(this).siblings(".button").unbind("click");

    if($(this).hasClass("rett"))
    {
        rettVar++;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                score: rettVar
            }
        })
        .always(function() {
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('There is an error occured.');
        })
        .done(function(result) {
            $("#antall-rett").html(rettVar);
            $("#score").html(rettVar);
            $(this).addClass("button-clicked-riktig");
        });     

    }

});
</script>
```

So this way the jQuery send back the score to the server, which is save it to you.

I hope it helps, but please consider, this code is only an example. I DO NOT recommend it to use in real-world application, since it has some security backdraws and maybe you should save the values to a database rather than a text file.